# Django Football Fixtures

Tags: django, for-loop, django-models, django-views, django-apps

I'm creating a football website in Django and have encountered a problem. Currently my homepage and fixture page are in different apps. I have the fixture page working so it displays the fixtures as added in by the admin page. I would like to include the next upcoming fixture on the homepage, but am having some problems importing the data.

Currently my fixtures/models.py file looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Fixture(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    opponents = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    match_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.match_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.opponents
```

and my fixtures/views.py looks like

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils import timezone
from fixtures.models import Fixture

def games(request):
    matches = Fixture.objects.filter(match_date__gte=timezone.now()).order_by('match_date')
    return render_to_response('fixtures/games.html', {'matches':matches
    })
```

My home/models.py looks like:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

from fixtures.models import Fixture

class First(models.Model):
    firstfixture = models.ForeignKey('fixtures.Fixture')
```

and home/views.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from home.models import First

def index(request):
    matches = First.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('home/index.html', {'matches':matches
    })
```

I have tried many combinations for my for loop but nothing displays the required information. My for loop which works for the fixtures app is(in HTML);

```
  {% for fixture in matches %}
      <div>
          <p>Vs {{ fixture.firstfixture.opponents }} - {{ fixture.firstfixture.match_date }}</p>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must call `all` as a function; otherwise it is just a callable.

```
matches = First.objects.all()
```

instead of

```
matches = First.objects.all
```

**EDIT**: You must actually access the FK of your First instance in order to get `opponents`.

```
{% for fixture in matches %}
    <div>
        <p>Vs {{ fixture.firstfixture.opponents }} - {{ fixture.firstfixture.match_date }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: See edit; `First` instances have no `opponents` or `match_date` attributes; you must access the related `Fixture` instance as shown above.

Comment: Sorry, still no change

Comment: Also, be sure to not call `matches.all` in the template; instead, just use `matches`. You are accessing a Queryset of First instances.

Comment: Yeah, once again no change. It doesn't display any error codes just the for loop doesn't output anything